# Spring @Transactional propagation is not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions, transactional

I have a very simple code comprising of Service -> RequestProcessor -> DAO having 2-3 classes (interface, abstract, concrete) in each layer.

Service layer:-

```
public interface Service {
   public void saveOrUpdate(Object entity, String operationName);
 }
}

public abstract class AbstractService implements Service{

   public abstract ReqProcessor getRP();
   @Override
   public void saveOrUpdate(Object entity, String operationName) {
     ReqProcessor hiberTestRP = getRP();
     hiberTestRP.saveOrUpdate(entity, operationName);
 }
}

@Component
public class ServiceImpl extends AbstractService {

  @Autowired
  public ReqProcessor hibertestRPImpl;

  @Override
  public HiberTestRP getRP() {
    return hibertestRPImpl;
 }
}
```

ReqProcessor layer:-

```
public interface ReqProcessor {
   public void saveOrUpdate(Object entity, String operationName);
   public void saveObject();
 }
}

public abstract class AbstractReqProcessor  implements ReqProcessor {
@Override
public void saveOrUpdate(Object entity, String operationName) {
    saveObject();
 }
}

@Component
public class ReqProcessorImpl extends AbstractReqProcessor {
 @Autowired
 public CustomHibernateDao customWSDaoImpl;

 @Override
 @Transactional(value="transactionManagerWS", propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
 public void saveObject() {
  // object created //
  customWSDaoImpl.saveOrUpdate(object);  // exception is thrown at this line
 }
}
```

DAO layer:-

```
public interface CustomHibernateDao {
  public void saveOrUpdate(Object entity, String operationName);
}

@Repository
@Transactional(value="transactionManagerWS", propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY)
public class CustomWSDaoImpl implements CustomHibernateDao {

 @Autowired
 public SessionFactory sessionFactoryWS;

 protected Session getCurrentSession() {
    return sessionFactoryWS.getCurrentSession();
 }

 @Override
 public void saveOrUpdate(Object entity, String operationName) {
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
 }
}
```

I get the following exception at the commented line :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:359)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:447)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.saveOrUpdate(Unknown Source)
```

The code works absolutely fine when the abstract classes are removed, with only interfaces and their implementing classes remaining. But with the above setup, the transaction is not being propagated from ReqProcessor layer to the DAO layer. Please help. (Dont mind the 'public' accessors everywhere, it's just for testing)
I have also searched on SO and other forums but couldnt find a solution.

Comment: Works as designed... The `@Transactional` is on a method that is called from the same object, as spring uses proxies to apply aop that call never passes through the proxy.

Comment: Try to change from `@Component` to `@Service` annotation on ReqProcessorImpl and ServiceImpl

Comment: @StanislavL thanks for the reply but that wont work because `@Service` is only a specialized `@Component` with no significant additional features. `@Transactional` works fine with `@Component`.

Comment: @M.Deinum +1 for the right input. Didnt realize that. Thanks

Comment: @M.Deinum you just saved me. I didn't realise/had forgotten this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @m-deinum has mentioned, Spring uses proxies to add "transactional" functionality, and this feature does not work when you call method annotated with `@Transactional` from another method of the class.

You have two ways to fix the problem:

1. In `AbstractReqProcessor` autowire `ApplicationContext` and then use it to get a bean of `CustomHibernateDao` type. On this retrieved object you can call `saveObject` - then the `transactional` magic happens.
2. The more preferred way is to annotate method `saveOrUpdate` of class `AbstractService` with `@Transactional` annotation too - then it will work again.

But I think you know the cause of the problem now and you can find another - more suitable for you - way.

Comment: Thank you. Both the approaches are working fine. I got the 1st approach but can you please explain a bit how the 2nd approach works. I mean what difference did it make when @Transactional is shifted from concrete class to the abstract class?

Comment: Well, it's not about shifting of `@Transactional` annotation at all. At first, I suggest you to read the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative point 17.5.1: "caller invokes proxy, not target", but it does not work when you call a method in another method of the same class.